# what is the privilege of the Postgres user created by gcp

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I created a Postgres instance, database and user in GCP, which did not ask me anything about setting user privilege. and it did not ask how the user will relate to the database.

When I check user permission using `psql`, I saw below info. Looks like the user has very power permission?

So, how do I grant user: myuser to admin permission only to the database: mydatabase?

```
mydatabase=>\l
Name   | owner |Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | Access privileges 
mydatabase | cloudsqlsuperuser | UTF8  | en_US.UTF8 |en_US.UTF8 |
... 

mydatabase=>\du
Role name| List of roles Attributes| Member of                                            
myuser   | Create role, Create DB  | {cloudsqlsuperuser}
cloudsqlsuperuser  | Create role, Create DB  | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend}
...
```

I believe the question is nothing to do with Terraform but here is my Terraform code in case it helps to figure out the answer:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "mypostgres" {...}

resource "google_sql_database" "mypostgres_db" {
  name  = "mydatabase"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.mypostgres.name
  ...
}

resource "google_sql_user" "mypostgres_user" {
  name     = "myuser"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.mypostgres.name
  password = "mypassword"
  ...
}
```

Comment: hey there! could you please share if you are using Cloud SQL or if you have your DB within a GCE?

Comment: I am using Cloud SQL. Thanks

Comment: @SamuelRomero: looks like any user created by GCP Cloud SQL does have very power privilege as super user. That is why GCP does not even ask me to link the user with database when I create the user: see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users?_ga=2.225112344.-341103751.1602097002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Cloud SQL, Google Cloud create a super admin user with all the permissions.

Then you can create new users, either builtin user (standard database user, with login and password) or Cloud IAM user that reuse the Cloud IAM capabilities to authenticate the users.

You can also create databases.

However, the RBAC is not a Google Cloud API, but a database feature, and you can't grant permission on a database to users. You need to run a command IN the database, and terraform can't do that for you.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume.  got it, cannot RBAC at GCP level or terrraform level. has to do it from psql level. Do you know how to grant user: myuser to admin permission only to the database: mydatabase using psql? GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydatabase TO myuser; I do not think it grants myuser permission to insert, delete tables of mydatabase.

Comment: It's the right command to grant all privileges. You can also narrow them to enforce least privileges by picking in this list: [SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER, CREATE, CONNECT, TEMPORARY, EXECUTE, USAGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-priv.html)

Comment: Thank you very much